# JSONPath Syntax when dot in key

Tags: json, jsonpath

Please forgive me if I use the incorrect terminology, I am quite the novice.

I have some simple JSON:

```
{
"properties": {
    "footer.navigationLinks": {
        "group": "layout"
    ,   "default": [
            {
                "text": "Link a"
            ,   "href": "#"
            }
        ]
    }
}
}
```

I am trying to pinpoint "footer.navigationLinks" but I am having trouble with the dot in the key name. I am using http://jsonpath.com/ and when I enter

```
$.properties['footer.navigationLinks']
```

I get 'No match'. If I change the key to "footernavigationLinks" it works but I cannot control the key names in the JSON file.

Please can someone help me target that key name?

Comment: have you tried `$["properties"]["footer.navigationLinks"]` ?  -- http://www.baeldung.com/guide-to-jayway-jsonpath

Comment: JSONPath has been forked and made available several languages (JavaScript, Node, PHP, Python, Java). Which JSONPath implementation are you using?

Comment: @Rob Yes, I have tried `$["properties"]["footer.navigationLinks"]` but that also returns 'No Match'. @trincot I believe its Javascript. I'm assuming if I can get it to work in jsonpath.com then it will work in my project. Thanks for your replies

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This issue was reported in 2007 as [issue #4 - Member names containing dot fail](https://code.google.com/archive/p/jsonpath/issues/4) and fixed.

The fix is *not* present in this online [jsonpath.com implementation](http://jsonpath.com/), but it is fixed in [this old archive](https://code.google.com/archive/p/jsonpath/source/default/source) and probably in most of the forks that have been created since (like [here](https://github.com/s3u/JSONPath) and [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jsonpath)).

#### Details about the bug

A comparison between the buggy and 2007-corrected version of the code, reveals that the correction was made in the private `normalize` function.

In the 2007-corrected version it reads:

```
normalize: function(expr) {
    var subx = [];
    return expr.replace(/[\['](\??\(.*?\))[\]']|\['(.*?)'\]/g, function($0,$1,$2){
        return "[#"+(subx.push($1||$2)-1)+"]";
    })  /* http://code.google.com/p/jsonpath/issues/detail?id=4 */
    .replace(/'?\.'?|\['?/g, ";")
    .replace(/;;;|;;/g, ";..;")
    .replace(/;$|'?\]|'$/g, "")
    .replace(/#([0-9]+)/g, function($0,$1){
         return subx[$1];
    });
},
```

The first and last `replace` in that sequence make sure the second `replace` does not interpret a point in a property name as a property separator.

I had a look at the more up-to-date forks that have been made since then, and the code has evolved enormously since.

#### Conclusion:

[jsonpath.com](http://jsonpath.com/) is based on an outdated version of JSONPath and is not reliable for previewing what current libraries would provide you with.

Comment: Thanks so much for the explanation, it seems that I was on the right track after all so that's encouraging.

Answer (score 11):

Having a json response:

```
{
  "0": {
    "SKU": "somevalue",
    "Merchant.Id": 234
    }
}
```

I can target a key with a . (dot) in the name.

```
jsonPath.getJsonObject("0.\"Merchant.Id\"")
```

**Note**: the quotes and the fact that they are escaped.

**Note** not sure of other versions, but I'm using

> 'com.jayway.restassured', name: 'json-path', version: '2.9.0'

A few samples/solutions I've seen, was using singe quotes with brackets, but did not work for me.

Answer (score 11):

For information, [jsonpath.com](https://jsonpath.com) has been patched since the question was asked, and it now works for the example given in the question. I tried these paths successfully:

- `$.properties['footer.navigationLinks']`
- `$.properties.[footer.navigationLinks]`
- `$.properties.['footer.navigationLinks']`
- `$['properties']['footer.navigationLinks']`
- `$.['properties'].['footer.navigationLinks']`
- `properties.['footer.navigationLinks']`
- etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can encapsulate the 'key with dots' with single quotes as below

```
response.jsonpath().get("properties.'footer.navigationLinks'")
```

Or even escape the single quotes as shown:

```
response.jsonpath().get("properties.\'footer.navigationLinks\'")
```

Both work fine

Comment: You need to explain your answer.