# jsonPath and email address

Tags: jsonpath

I am using [jsonpath.com](http://jsonpath.com/) to try to use an **email address** as the **KEY**.

so my data might look like this:

```
"phoneNumbers": [
    {
      "type"  : "iPhone",
      "bob@gmail.com": 123456,
      "number": "0123-4567-8888"
    },
```

however, i am unable to reference the email address:

```
$.phoneNumbers[0]['type']             // iPhone
$.phoneNumbers[0]['number']           // 0123-4567-8888
$.phoneNumbers[0]['bob@gmail.com']    // no match
$.phoneNumbers[0]['bob\@gmail.com']   // no match
$.phoneNumbers[0]['bob\@gmail\.com']  // no match
```

how may i specify a jsonPath key using an email address?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The dot in `.com` is the problem. See [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40191184/2751039). It would seem that it should be possible to do `$.phoneNumbers[0]['bob@gmail.com']`, but not on jsonpath.com

The key statement in that answer:

> [jsonpath.com](http://jsonpath.com) is based on an outdated version of JSONPath and is not
>   reliable for previewing what current libraries would provide you with.

Comment: thank you very much - it would appear the npm version works fine.  this makes me wonder if the jsonpath.com site will ever use a more current version?