# How to get object's value if key name contains dots in jsonpath

Tags: python, jsonpath

The following code all returns False.

```py
import jsonpath
data = {'layers': {'urlencoded-form.key': ["1234"]}}

assert jsonpath.jsonpath(data, '$..urlencoded-form.key') == False
assert jsonpath.jsonpath(data, '$..[urlencoded-form.key]') == False
assert jsonpath.jsonpath(data, '$..["urlencoded-form.key"]') == False
assert jsonpath.jsonpath(data, '$.."urlencoded-form.key"') == False
```

Comment: Does it work if you use quotes like this?
"$..['urlencoded-form.key']"

Comment: Does this answer your question? [JSONPath Syntax when dot in key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40187231/jsonpath-syntax-when-dot-in-key)

Comment: It's not work either.

Comment: perhaps it's a bug in the library, maybe try a different one... https://github.com/h2non/jsonpath-ng claims to be standards compliant

Comment: Putting it quotes the way @Ada commented is the correct way to reference these kinds of properties.  That said, the third option in your code should work.  I agree it's likely a bug.